# how to make line break in html without br

Tags: html, css

i have a lot of content and i am going to upload it to my website, and in website it will look like with no line breaks. and it will take a lot of time to add in content - `<br>`. Is there any other way to break lines?
Thank you!

Comment: you should wrap paragraphs with `<p>paragraph stuff</p>` tags which will provide the correct spacing.

Comment: but, Aaron, it will take a lots of time too. I have about 300MB of only text and it will take about year to add paragraph to them.

Comment: where should the lines break?

Comment: Can we get a snippet of text so we know what it looks like? Preferably in a place you'd like for there to be a line break. There's not enough information here to actually provide you with a good answer.

Comment: http://s27.postimg.org/yrzwnymmb/image.jpg i have text like this

Comment: and i want to make line breaks on every line

Comment: If you want more space between every single line, you might be better off just using CSS to add more line-spacing instead of line breaks.

Comment: The link http://s27.postimg.org/yrzwnymmb/image.jpg is dead.

Comment: There is a <pre> tag, but that is very similar to <blockquote>.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll assume your original content has breaks caused by carriage returns or line feeds, but they're not rendered that way in your HTML.

To fix that, add CSS style `pre-wrap`:

```css
div {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.  Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Comment: thats what i need, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can give width to paragraph tag or its parent tag. Please post your work in jsfiddle. So i can edit it and give it to you

Comment: http://s27.postimg.org/yrzwnymmb/image.jpg please, just try a text like this and show me. unfortiunatly i cant share that information. thank you

Comment: you want that grey background full width or half width of browser?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sagartt/ky57u48k/ here is my work. i made this for half width of browser

Answer (score 0):

I imagine it would take even longer to wrap paragraphs in `<p></p>` than it would to add `<br>` between paragraphs.  If I were going to take a huge amount of raw text and put it into content on a web page I would paste it into (or since I am a programmer write a program) a program that would make the conversion.

As I'm writing I'm thinking and wondering if you took your text and put it into MS Word and saved it as an HTML and made the format corrections could you get output from that that would work for your purposes?

Comment: Ok I didn't realize it would leave out the /< p />  and the /< b />

I hope you can figure where they belong.

Comment: copying/pasting to MS Word, than saving will take a lots of time too.
Can you help me to making program for auto adding paragraphs/br-s?

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS. For instance, if you have several paragraphs of text you can have a space between each one by just giving them a bottom margin as:

```
p { margin-bottom : 1em; }
```

That will give a complete blank line between each paragraph (or you could have 0.5em, say, to get half that amount of space, or any other measure. If you haven't used CSS before, now would be the time to learn, and it's pretty easy to learn the basics.

You can add CSS at the top of your HTML in the head section, for now (later learn how to put it into a separate file), doing:

```
<head>
....[other stuff here]
<style type="text/css">
p { margin-bottom : 1em; }
</style>
</head>
```

Comment: GuyH unfotiunatly, i have no paragraphs in my content. there are a bunch of raw text. no html, just text. adding paragraphs will take a lots of time.