# Line break in popover/tooltip of kableExtra table in R markdown

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, knitr, kableextra

I would like to have text in a pop up show upon hovering over a cell of a table. That works, however, I do not manage to get line breaks into that text. My example is adapted from here:https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_html.html

````
---
title: "Line break in popover"
output: html_document
---

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); 
});

</script>

```{r echo = FALSE}

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(kableExtra)

popover_dt <- data.frame(
  position = c("top", "bottom", "right", "left"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
popover_dt$`Hover over these items` <- cell_spec(
  paste("Message on", popover_dt$position), # Cell texts
  popover = spec_popover(content = c("line\nbreak", "line<br/>break", "line&#013;break", "line&#10;break")))

kbl(popover_dt, escape = FALSE) %>%
  kable_paper("striped", full_width = FALSE)

```
````

However, what I do not get to work is to make a line break between line and break in the pop up. I tried `\n`, `<br>`, `&#013;`, and `&#10;`. No attempt seems to work. Any idea how to solve that problem?

[image]

Comment: Try adding `html: true` in your js, like this: `$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({html: true});` then including `<br/>` should provide the line break

Comment: @Ben I did, see edited post. However, it still does not work. Did I put the line of course where it belongs? Sorry I have no idea of js. I only used R so far.

Comment: Nope - just add `html: true` to what you have --- here's the whole thing: `<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({html: true}); 
});
</script>` I'll provide an answer to clarify...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `html: true` to your javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({html: true}); 
});
</script>
```

Then `<br/>` should provide a line break.

Answer (score 1):

You could add custom css styling to the document, see [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34335642/13513328) :

````
---
title: "Line break in popover"
output: html_document
---

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); 
});
</script>

```{css, echo=FALSE}
div {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```{r echo = FALSE}

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(kableExtra)



popover_dt <- data.frame(
  position = c("top", "bottom", "right", "left"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
popover_dt$`Hover over these items` <- cell_spec(
  paste("Message on", popover_dt$position), # Cell texts
  popover = spec_popover(content = c("line\nbreak", "line<br>break", "line&#013;break", "line&#10;break")))

kbl(popover_dt, escape = FALSE) %>%
  kable_paper("striped", full_width = FALSE)

```
````

[image]